# Why not execute forkJoin in a test of Jest?

Tags: angular, jestjs

I have the next `.spec` in my project of Angular.

```
describe('JenkinsDataComponent', () => {
  let component: JenkinsDataComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<JenkinsDataComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [JenkinsDataComponent],
    imports: [
        ...
    ],
    providers: [
        I18N_PROVIDERS,
        { provide: AeEnvironmentService, useClass: MockAeEnvironmentService },
        { provide: JenkinsService, useClass: MockJenkinsService },
        { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'es-ES' },
    ],
    teardown: { destroyAfterEach: false }
})
    .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(JenkinsDataComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should grouped the components', () => {
    const arrayResult = [
      {
        label: 'Microservice',
        value: 'microservice',
        items: [
          {
            label: "security",
            value: "security"
          },
        ]
      }
    ]
    expect(component.groupedComponents[0].items).toEqual(arrayResult[0].items);
    expect(component.groupedComponents[0].items.length).toBe(1);
  });
```

And I have a mock for the service.

```
export class MockAeEnvironmentService extends AeEnvironmentService{

    listGroup = [
        {
          "microservice": "security-pro"
        }
    ]

    getGroup(groupId: string): Observable<any>{
      return of(this.listGroup);
    }
}
```

This test check that the `groupedComponents` variable is good initialized after a asynchronous request.

The code in the component below:

```
export class JenkinsDataComponent implements OnInit {
 ngOnInit(): void {
    ...
    this.loadComponents();
  }
 loadComponents(){
    var arrayRequest = [];
    var componentsAll = [];
    this.jobs.forEach(job => {
      if (job.value !== Constants.KEY_SRV_ALL) {
        var observable$ = this.environmentService.getGroup(job.value).pipe(tap(components => {
          // This code is executed in Jest, so it is good
          var componentsArrayReplace = components.map(element => element[job.value].replace(/-pre$|-pro$/,''));
          var element = {
            label: job.label, value: job.value,
            items: [...new Set(componentsArrayReplace)].map(value => ({ label: value , value: value})),
          }
          componentsAll.push(element);
        }))
        arrayRequest.push(observable$);
      }
    })

    forkJoin(arrayRequest).subscribe(
      response => {
        // This code is never executed in Jest
        this.groupedComponents = componentsAll;
        this.selectedComponent = this.groupedComponents[0].items[0].label;
        this.loadData();
      }
    );
  }
}
```

However, it seems that the code inside the subscribe is never executed because the test result looks like this:

[image]

Why is the variable never initialised? Why does this happen? Is there anything wrong in the code?

Thank you in advance.

- Jest version: 27.4.7
- Angular version: 13.3.3

Comment: How is jobs set? You can also set a debugger statement in the component and run the test while the dev tools is open and inspect where it goes wrong.

Comment: You could also insert for example tick(100); before the expect statmenets just to see if there some sync/async issues